# PHP Google API Chart

Tags: php, html

I would like to draw a Google chart. In the example, we get the following url to embeded into our HTML code :

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40
```

How can I replace the data `t:60,40` by an array of data I get from a db ?

Let's say I have the following array, `$chartdata` :

```
$chartdata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now, I would like to draw the same chart as above, but using my `$chartdata`.

The following method is not working :

```
<?php
echo "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&amp;chs=250x100&amp;chd=t:" . $chartdata ."'>";
?>
```

Does someone has an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
<?php
echo "<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&amp;chs=250x100&amp;chd=t:" . implode(",", $chartdata) . "'>";
?>
```